# PowerShell script freezes after creating a folder when run in system context

Tags: powershell

Im developing a PowerShell script to deploy some application.. this script is run via our so called "Environment Manager" in the context of a (domain) system user.

The problem occurs on following line:

`New-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Launcher" -ItemType Directory`

**The folder is created, but the script kind of freezes.**
I don't get any error output in my logs or the PowerShell transcript and the script doesn't continue and doesn't return. (`$PSScriptRoot` becomes "C:\Users\Public".)

When I run the script as user it runs without any issues. Even when running it with PSExec as system user it works fine.

I'm at my wits' end.

Best Benjamin

Comment: The 'problem' line looks OK as far as PowerShell goes.  I'd suspect _our so called "Environment Manager"_.  From the limited information, I'd check that the user has permission to write to `$PSScriptRoot` and that your "Environment Manager" isn't confused by unexpected output, since that line would produce some by default (append `| Out-Null` to discard it).  Maybe it's the following code that is the actual problem - what does it try to do next?

Comment: @boxdog thank you! Somehow the output is freezing it. I redirect everything to my log now and it's working.